# Why doesn't Postfix reject a specific client's connection attempts?

Tags: firewall, postfix, smtp, sasl

My SMTP server is being probed. It looks like a brute force attach on SASL, where they're going through a password dictionary.

Having seen thousands of these lines in the log files

```
Sep 18 14:09:52 xxx postfix/smtpd[7412]: connect from ca255.calcit.fastwebserver.de[146.0.42.124]
Sep 18 14:09:55 xxx postfix/smtpd[7412]: warning: ca255.calcit.fastwebserver.de[146.0.42.124]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Sep 18 14:09:55 xxx postfix/smtpd[7412]: lost connection after AUTH from ca255.calcit.fastwebserver.de[146.0.42.124]
Sep 18 14:09:55 xxx postfix/smtpd[7412]: disconnect from ca255.calcit.fastwebserver.de[146.0.42.124]
```

I modified my main.cf like this:

```
inet_interfaces = all
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_address

smtpd_client_restrictions =  check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/maps/access_client,
                             permit_mynetworks,
                             reject

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/maps/access_client,
                               permit_mynetworks,
                               reject_non_fqdn_sender,
                               reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
                               reject_unknown_sender_domain,
                               reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
                               permit_sasl_authenticated,
                               reject_unauth_pipelining,
                               reject_unauth_destination,
                               reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
                               reject_rbl_client list.dsbl.org
                               permit

broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
```

And my /etc/postfix/maps/access_client only has this line:

`146.0.42.124 REJECT`

However after restarting postfix there is still no change in behaviour, I still see the same error, so SASL is still being checked, even though I thought with these settings the client would be rejected based on its IP address before SASL even comes into the game ?

A 2nd question is - I am relaying outgoing mail traffic from one machine to another on the internal network - apart from the 'relayhost' setting on the machine that just relays, can I keep the rest of the postfix settings the same on both ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postfix doesn't evaluate the `smtpd_client_restrictions` until the `RCPT TO` (or `ETRN`) command is sent.

http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#timing

> Current Postfix versions postpone the evaluation of client, helo and sender restriction lists until the RCPT TO or ETRN command. This behavior is controlled by the smtpd_delay_reject parameter. Restriction lists are still evaluated in the proper order of (client, helo, etrn) or (client, helo, sender, relay, recipient, data, or end-of-data) restrictions. When a restriction list (example: client) evaluates to REJECT or DEFER the restriction lists that follow (example: helo, sender, etc.) are skipped.

Thus you can get around this by setting the following in your `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_delay_reject = no
```

As for your second question, there are so many controls for postfix, this is near impossible to answer without having complete details of your network, postfix configuration, and client configuration. Best way is to just try it.

Comment: Good pointer which is missed in many howtos. I was about to use that – until I've read the entire section behind the link. Make sure to check the bullet-points at its end for side effects. // I wish there were a way e.g. the SASL AUTH could be "faked" in such cases, so the client is rejected at the proper place (with the proper information gathered) without being given the possibility of "brute-forcing SASL" – and without the other trade-offs mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to disable SASL AUTH for specific IPs or IP ranges *without* the side-effects of `smtpd_delay_reject = no`, take a look at the [`smtpd_discard_ehlo_keyword_address_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_discard_ehlo_keyword_address_maps) keyword. Example configuration and explanation:

---

#### Configuration

First, we set up the keyword in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_discard_ehlo_keyword_address_maps = cidr:/etc/postfix/esmtp_cidr
```

Now we define our blacklist in `/etc/postfix/esmtp_cidr` (the file we just specified):

```
# /etc/postfix/esmtp_cidr
91.200.12.0/24  auth
155.133.82.77   auth
146.0.42.124    auth
```

As this is a `cidr:` list file, no `postmap` run is required. But we need to tell Postfix to reload its configuration:

```
service postfix reload
```

---

#### Explanation

Now, what does that mean? For the addresses specified (either full IP or an IP range in this example), we told Postfix to disable a specific ESMTP feature: `AUTH`. This means, the hosts covered no longer can use SASL. Let's check the log:

```
Aug 11 22:37:39 xxx postfix/smtpd[32630]: connect from unknown[91.200.12.98]
Aug 11 22:37:39 xxx postfix/smtpd[32630]: discarding EHLO keywords: AUTH
Aug 11 22:37:39 xxx postfix/smtpd[32630]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[91.200.12.98]
Aug 11 22:37:39 xxx postfix/smtpd[32630]: disconnect from unknown[91.200.12.98]
```

So we got what we want, without having to use `smtpd_delay_reject = no`, and thus don't need to fear the side-effects of the latter.

Note: the very same way you can forbid clients to use other ESMTP features, such as pipelining or starttls. A list of available keywords can e.g. be found [in this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_SMTP). Other than with [smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks), those keywords will not only not be announced, but they won't be accepted at all – as the log shows.